# Aggregate array of object to single distinct value of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, array-reduce

I want to aggregate array of object into single object with each object having distinct value. But My code is not giving me desired output. Can someone please help me?

```
My Input : 
    [{
        "obj1" : "value1",
        "obj2" : ["abc", "def"],
        "obj3" : ["ghi"],
        "obj4" : "value4",
    },
    {
        "obj1" : "value2",
        "obj2" : ["abc", "mno"],
        "obj3" : ["klm"],
        "obj4" : "value4",
    }]


Output I want:
{
    "obj1" : ["value1","value2"]
    "obj2" : ["abc", "def","mno"],
    "obj3" : ["ghi","klm"],
    "obj4" : ["value4"]
}

My Code:
const result = filterData.reduce((a,c) => 
  (Object.keys(c).map(k => a[k] = [...a[k] || [], c[k]]), a), {})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I use some helpers from lodash to solve your problem.

```js
const input = [{
        "obj1" : "value1",
        "obj2" : ["abc", "def"],
        "obj3" : ["ghi"],
        "obj4" : "value4",
    },
    {
        "obj1" : "value2",
        "obj2" : ["abc", "mno"],
        "obj3" : ["klm"],
        "obj4" : "value4",
    }]
    
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return _.union(objValue, srcValue);
  }
}
    
const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const modifiedCur = _.mapValues(cur, function(o) { return typeof o === 'string' ? [o]: o; }); 
  acc = _.mergeWith(acc, modifiedCur, customizer);
  return acc
},{})    
    
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a single object from an array of objects using `array#reduce`. You can get distinct value using `Set`.

```js
const data = [{ "obj1" : "value1", "obj2" : ["abc", "def"], "obj3" : ["ghi"], "obj4" : "value4", }, { "obj1" : "value2", "obj2" : ["abc", "mno"], "obj3" : ["klm"], "obj4" : "value4", }],
      result = data.reduce((r,o) => {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
          r[k] = [...new Set((r[k] || []).concat(o[k]))];
        });
        return r;
      },{});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why do we need r[k] = r[k] || [];  line? To check if the key exists?

Comment: It was initializing the array for the new key and the old key, it was not doing anything. I have updated the code

Comment: Great,it is much easier now to understand.